# Efficient way to generate sorted vector of pairs in C++

Tags: c++, std

I am attempting to generate a sorted vector `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` from a set of integer. By iterating the integer set, the value of the integer will be set to the first value of the pair and the second value of the pair will be computed by another function. All pairs should be sorted according to the second value in my final vector. To this end I have two plans to generated the vector: either I "insert" the pair to the correct position (by iterating from the vector begin and compare the second-value), or I simply do push-back and sort (by `std::sort` with some compare-function) the whole vector after all pairs have been pushed. So which plan would be more efficient? (Or there is an even better approach?)

Comment: Have you considered an `std::set<std::pair<int, int>>` with a custom comparator instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: If they need to continually add and remove items that's a good idea (or as I note in my answer, perhaps a `std::multimap<int, int>` mapping from generated `int`s to the `int` that generated them). If it's statically built once and never modified afterwards, I'd probably favor a bulk build of the `vector` and a single bulk sort.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's actually exact the point. In the paper which I was reading, the author suggested sorted arrays (I think sorted vector shall be the same) instead of tree-like data structures and it was claimed that in many cases sorted arrays may work better due to e.g. x86' architecture which optimises for operations of contiguous blocks of memory. I'm trying to test this.

Comment: @Y.Tang There are certainly good reasons to prefer `std::vector` and data locality is one of them.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This may be a possibility, but another issue is there are (always, in my case) many duplications in the second value of the pair.

Comment: @Y.Tang: If duplicates exist and should be kept, that just means switching to `std::multiset` or `std::multimap` instead of `std::set`/`std::map`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger ah yes, good idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generating the whole `vector` and sorting as the final step is almost certainly the way to go. Assuming the generated values are semi-random, attempting to insert to maintain sorted order would involve a continuously growing `O(n)` insertion cost (the `O(log n)` binary search cost is less of a problem in theory, but given the semi-random access, might be worse than the insert cost in practice), making the overall construction time `O(n²)` (`n` insertions costing `O(n)` work each).

By contrast, generating the whole thing and sorting at the end is `O(n)` to build the `vector`, and `O(n log n)` to sort it.

The only time to consider inserting into it preserving order is when you have a small number of items to insert into a large existing `vector`. Of course, if you're in that scenario, you're probably better off using a `std::set` or `std::multiset` (or in this case, a `std::multimap<int, int>` mapping your generated values to the `int` that generated them) to make the modification work consistently `O(log n)` per operation.